# Использование DLL в приложении UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

Мне надо вызвать функцию из dll.
Вот код:

```
    [DllImport(@"C:\path\Name.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "FuncName")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    static extern char FuncName();

    public bool publicFuncName()
    {
        var ans = FuncName();
        return ans == '1' ? true : false;
    }
```

И при вызове этой функции появляется ошибка:

```
 Unable to load DLL 'C:\path\Name.dll': Отказано в доступе. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

Что не так? Можете подсказать или дать ссылки на соответствующие материалы?

Comment: А студию от администратора пробовали запускать?

Comment: @YuryBakharev Только что попробовал, все тоже самое.

Comment: @YuryBakharev А так вообще правильно? Может функции из DLL нужно по другому вызывать?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/Ru-ru/library/mt186162.aspx

Comment: @Serginio Не нашел в вашей статье, как динамически подключить библиотеку и вызвать функцию на C#.

Comment: Приложения UWP могут динамически загружать сборки **только** из appx package. Вероятно, к `DllImport` это тоже относится.

Answer (score 1):

Ну во первых вы точно должны знать сигнатуру функции, но вообще вызывается она так

```
 [DllImport("TNHotkeys.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    static extern int Test(int b1, int b2);
```

где Test - название функции на длл, у которой для примера два целочисленных параметра и возвращает она тоже целое число!

Comment: По-моему, дело не доходит до вызова функции. Сама библиотека не грузится.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov К сожалению, все именно так. А как добавить DLL в appx package?

Comment: @AynurSibagatullin - я не спец по UWP. Вероятно, следует задать отдельный новый вопрос на эту тему. Комментарий мало кто заметит.